# css align objects

Tags: css

My question is how can align objects to look like this without the dots:

> 1234
>   ..................................................................................................................................................................................1234....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................1234

I know this can be done with different class and then different margin-top. But I have many objects. Is there a way to do it direct in css without javascript?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you can do this with 
<ul></ul> tag but i'm not sure about what you're asking for

Comment: Looks like nested `ul`s indeed. Then you can css the bullets to not be displayed. Something in that direction possibly.

Answer (score 0):

give `float:left;` or `margin-left : 0px;` property to all the objects.

Comment: I want every "1234" (some object) to be on a new line and to be like a ladder

Answer (score 0):

You just use the `margin-left` property

With the margin property you can align elements and push them from the left, right, top or bottom as you prefer.

For example :

```
<span style="margin-left:0px;">1234</span><br/>
<span style="margin-left:30px;">1234</span><br/>
<span style="margin-left:60px;">1234</span>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aoxkF)

If you wish to achieve your example and without `<br/>` then i would suggest the following.

```
<span style="display:block; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:15px;">1234</span>
<span style="display:block; margin-left:30px; margin-bottom:15px;">1234</span>
<span style="display:block; margin-left:60px; margin-bottom:15px;">1234</span>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HIkrc)

With the `display:block;` you make a div style of attribute out of it and allows you to use `margin-bottom`.
With the `margin-bottom` you push the next element down which causes a extra line in between.